# When I use the threshold method to extract water , why are there many areas that are incorrectly classified as water?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using Sentinel-1 radar data. This is a misclassified area:

[image: Misclassified area]

What caused this, can I improve it? This is my code.

```
    geometry = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[73.9753904127242, 54.03780906107912],
          [73.9753904127242, 16.93758362646061],
          [137.6082029127242, 16.93758362646061],
          [137.6082029127242, 54.03780906107912]]], null, false);
dataset = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME","China"));
// Load region defined by polygon and add it to the map
//Load Sentinel-1 SAR collection and filter according to data collection type
var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(dataset)
  .filterDate('2016-01-01','2016-12-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))

//Add first image to map to get an idea of what a SAR image looks like  
//Map.addLayer(S1.first(),{bands: 'VV',min: -18, max: 0}, 'SAR image')
// Filter speckle noise
var filterSpeckles = function(img) {
  var vv = img.select('VV') //select the VV polarization band
  var vv_smoothed = vv.focal_median(100,'circle','meters').rename('VV_Filtered') //Apply a focal median filter
  return img.addBands(vv_smoothed) // Add filtered VV band to original image
}

// Map speckle noise filter across collection. Result is same collection, with smoothed VV band added to each image
S1 = S1.map(filterSpeckles)

//Add speckle filtered image to map to sompare with raw SAR image
//Map.addLayer(S1.first(),{bands: 'VV_Filtered',min: -18, max: 0}, 'Filtered SAR image')
//Here we are using -16. This is only an approximation and will result in some errors. Try adjusting the 
var classifyWater = function(img) {
  var vv = img.select('VV_Filtered')
  var water = vv.lt(-16).add(1).rename('Water')  //Identify all pixels below threshold and set them equal to 1. All other pixels set to 0
  water = water.updateMask(water) //Remove all pixels equal to 0
  return img.addBands(water)  //Return image with added classified water band
}

//Map classification across sentinel-1 collection and print to console to inspect
S1 = S1.map(classifyWater).select('Water');
var extracted=S1.median().clip(dataset);
Map.addLayer(extracted,{min: 0, max: 2,alette:['white','black']},'water');
Export.image.toAsset({
  image:extracted,
  description: 'sentinel_Threshold_2016_china',
  scale:30,
  region:geometry,
  maxPixels:1e13,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `classifyWater()` is probably not doing what you want it to do. It's at least not doing what the code comments says. Do you want water pixels to be `1` and the rest of the pixels to be masked out (what I figure the comments says), or do you want water pixels to be `2` and other pixels `1` (what the code is actually doing)? This give you `1` for water, the rest masked out:

```
var classifyWater = function(img) {
  var vv = img.select('VV_Filtered')
  var water = vv.lt(-24).rename('Water') //Identify all pixels below threshold and set them equal to 1. All other pixels set to 0
  water = water.updateMask(water) //Remove all pixels equal to 0
  return img.addBands(water) //Return image with added classified water band
}
```

Not only water give you low a `VV`. You will get a lot of misclassified pixels with this approach. In any case, the threshold seems to be too high. Add `VV_Filtered` to the map and inspect some pixels. That might help you pick a more suitable threshold.

Sentinel 1 also come with some noise around the edges that you might want to mask out.

```
  var angle = img.select('angle')
  img = img.updateMask(angle.gt(31).and(angle.lt(45))) // Mask the border of the image
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a609a770336f4f39dd46a40d82593be

To create a water mask from Sentinel 1, you might have better luck with a [supervised classification](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification). Maybe include both `VV`, `VH` and the ratio between `VV` and `VH`.